# Generating one unique string from 2 keywords

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a way to generate one unique string from 2 keywords no-matter the position they are input in.

**EDIT:** The keywords are numbers rather than alphabets. The example below is just for illustration

**Example:**

```
keyword1 ="apple"
keyword2 ="ball"

keyword1+keyword2 = "appleball";
keyword2+keyword1 = "appleball";
```

Comment: You are applying anyway an order to input keywords that make the output (keyword1 considered always the first keyword).

Comment: Does sorting them alphabetically work for you?

Comment: @Ludwik, i would basically have 2 unique numbers rather than alphabets.

Comment: What determines the order then (how do you know which number should go 1st)? Also, where you get the keywords (input, db)?

Comment: @JaneDoe well, I will be trying Nina Scholz answer by converting my unique number to string. It is not about where it comes from or which goes first and second, it should give the same output whichever goes first between the same numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort the strings for the same order and join it.

```js
function getUnique(a, b) {
    return [a.toString(), b.toString()].sort().join('');
}

console.log(getUnique("apple", "ball"));
console.log(getUnique("ball", "apple"));
```

For numbers, i suggest to use a separator and numerical order.

```js
function getUnique(a, b) {
    return [a, b].sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; }).join('|');
}

console.log(getUnique(1, 111)); // 1|111
console.log(getUnique(111, 1)); // 1|111
console.log(getUnique(11, 11)); // 11|11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat` method. See this example:

```
var str1 = "Hello ";
var str2 = "world!";
var res = str1.concat(str2);
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp

Comment: str2.concat(str1) should give me the same is what i am expecting.

Comment: Ok, sorry. This wont help you so.